# Ford Focus CC missing panel

Tags: ford, focus, body-work

I have a Ford Focus CC-3 2008 with a missing panel that I want to replace, however I don't know what it's called or where to find it (I'm in the UK). The panel is seen when the roof is down and it covers some of the roof mechanics, as shown in the picture I've provided.

If anybody could offer me some advice for this, it would be much appreciated!

[image: Ford Focus CC missing panel]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Something you might be able to do is if you can gain access to the other side piece just like this one, the part number is usually stamped onto the backside of the piece itself. You could take that part number to figure out what the piece name is and then cross reference it to this one. I've been looking for a few minutes and haven't come up with anything for you.

Comment: Paulster2 has given some great advice. For me, when that didn't work, I took the car to the dealership and asked them to quote the part for me. They were nice enough to give me the Ford part number and price. Once I had that, I was able to search the internet and buy it for much less.

Comment: Both of these suggestions are top notch! And I agree with them.

Comment: Thanks guys, I went ahead and took the other side piece off, there was a few numbers on there but unfortunately none of them were a part number or part specific. I will hopefully be having a mechanic look at the car so I'll see what they think, otherwise I'll give the dealership a try!

Answer (score -1):

They are referred to as wind deflectors. They are common on many performance convertibles. I couldn't find any listings for the original Ford part. However they are available from sites similar to Cabrio Styling and Supply.

Comment: A search for a Ford Focus CC wind deflector brings up results for [these](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1117/6246/products/Ford_Focus_CC_06-10_Wind_Deflector_1024x1024.JPG?v=1472123809) which is not what I'm looking for, plus I already have one as seen in the picture I provided. I had a search on https://www.cabriosupply.co.uk/ but no luck.